# Angular, HTTP Get works, Post receives CORS error

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, cross-domain, csrf

**Setup**

I have an Angular app running in an iframe in a JSP application.  The JSP application is legacy and needs to stay.  Both JSP and Angular call the same REST services.  The JSP application does the login and receives a session cookie.  Since the Angular app is embedded in the JSP app on the SAME tomcat server, the cookies are transferred (at least what I understand).

```
tomcat
├── webapps
│   ├── jspapp
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── angularapp
│   │   ├── ...
```

**GET Code**

```
... build params ...
return http.get(url,
  { params: params }).pipe(
    map(
      (response: Response) => {
        ... handle response ...
        return data;
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  );
```

**GET Header**

```
GET http://severname:8080/jsprest/url/to/rest/service?param=value HTTP/1.1
Host: severname:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://severname:8080/angular/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=UNIQUEID; xcp-locale=en_US; x-csrf-token=SOMETOKEN
```

**POST Code**

```
... build body ...
return http.post(url, body, 
  { headers: { 'Accept': ['application/json', 'text/plain', '*/*'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

**POST Header**

```
POST  http://severname:8080/jsprest/url/to/rest/service HTTP/1.1
Host: severname:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 158
Accept: application/json,text/plain,*/*
Origin: http://severname:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://severname:8080/angular/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=UNIQUEID; xcp-locale=en_US; x-csrf-token=SOMETOKEN

{"body":"data","foo":"bar"}
```

**Error**

In the **browser console** I get following error,

> 403: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden error.

In **Tomcat** I get following error,

> CSRF token in cookies/request header is empty or values does not match

**Question**

I've verified the jessionid and csrf token are identical between the GET and POST.  Am I mis-understanding something fundamental here?  If what I'm trying do isn't the best way to handle this.  What is? The JSP application needs to exist as it provides needed functionality, Angular is there to provide the ability to display/interact with data in ways the JSP application can not.

Comment: What are you asking here? CORS has nothing to do with a lot of what you mentioned. If the browser makes a cross domain request, then the browser performs a OPTIONS pre-flight test. GET requests in HTML are not subject to the test as an exception, but all cross requests from JS require CORS. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Reactgular, my question is essentially why the GET works and the POST doesn't.  It's from the same angular page.  Your comment alludes to the fact that GET isn't checked but POST is.  If that is the case, then is the solution the one posted by Omkar below?  Also I've verified with Postman that the POST request I'm making is correct, albeit with Authentication instead of a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

- ***Reasons which produce CORS error-***

  1. Browser can't understand which server should have use to send the request
     from web to back-end. Because their are 2 servers  running for the
     same app,**first is your local angular server** which is localhost &
     **other is your back-end's server which is either tomcat or any** other,hence due to the conflicts in server browser doesn't understand
     the server to hit that request and hence CORS error occur.
  2. Silly spelling mistakes in your URL or missing of any part of URL.
- ***Prevention's or solution-***

  1. Allow all requests coming to backed server like GET, POST, DELETE,
     PUT etc..,like in spring you can use @Crossorigin("*").Instead of *
     you can use your preferences to allow in CrossOrigin.
  2. Avoid spelling mistakes and cutting parts of URL

> 403 means forbidden request-(Server restrict you to hit request)
>
> 401 means Unauthorised request-(Generally when no login data avail or token expires or no token in the request)

Comment: Omkar,  I'm running both angular and jsp on the same tomcat server.  Both URLs are http://tomcat:8080/angular and http://tomcat:8080/jsp.  I did a compile and deploy for Angular and then took the code and placed it in the tomcat webapp.  So there is no local angular server.

Comment: Have you gone through the " preventions or solution" of this answer?