# Angular with Java backend return CORS error

Tags: java, angular

I´m trying to connect a Angular web to Java backend. For do this i use different endpoints. Return

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

I try adding proxy.conf.json like this in angular

```
{
  "/URL/*": {
    "target": "ENDPOINT",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I try too modify .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

No works.

So: What´s is the properly way to abble CORS in angular endpoints?

**UPDATE**

httpOptions in angular

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
  })
};
```

Comment: Configure CORS on you backend API.

Comment: When you are requesting your endpoints, are the headers present? And if yes, do you by chance try to send an authorization header to your backend via a asynchronous request?

Comment: @leopal how can i to this?

Comment: @Smutje I update question with httpOptions. Can you post what i need to add it?

Comment: It depends on your API. For example, in case you are using spring there is a dedicated annotation @CrossOrigin

Comment: Check following link-It will helps you a lot - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964319/angular-http-get-works-post-receives-cors-error/56964966#56964966](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964319/angular-http-get-works-post-receives-cors-error/56964966#56964966)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the shitty world of modern Browsers :-)

If you use a `Authorization` header your Browser will perform a preflight request to check if your Browser has not been messed with via your Website and check the response. In particular, he will check if `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is valid and for requests containing a `Authorization` header that means that a wildcard (`*`) **is not valid**! To make a Backend CORS-able you must allow the Origin of the request as a explicit `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which leads many Backend developers to simply take the value of the `Origin` request header and put it into the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

So when your Browser requests the Backend during a preflight, your Backend has to respond similar to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <The requesting Origin must be included>
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

More on this can be found on Mozilla's page on CORS:  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: So i need to allow CORS  in frontend and backend?

Comment: What do you mean "allow cors in frontend"? But yes, if your Backend is not CORS-able, modern Browsers wouldn't be able to talk to them the way you designed it.